# User session with security

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies

I am a c# programmer. Now my current mission is want to create a user login asp.net website. I am quite new to this, now my problem is, i need to know what is the best to implement to my system. Since this system involved with the money, security is the priority of my website.

Now this is my issue

1) User login - Which is the best way to implement the user login authorization? If i go into cookies, will the hacker go into cookies there to hack it? if i go into querystring, this is very abviously if the hacker just need to take time to decrypt it. Should i use session?

2) Content - Will it be hack if i use cookies to pass the parameter to the next page? If the hacker doing like , when opening a new page, enter the debug mode, and he might have the chance to view what is the parameter when i create the cookies.

I need the security. Please help me what is the best method to create it. I am using c# asp.net

Comment: Session state completely resides on server-side, no matter which storage method you use in-memory or session state server or database. So unless your server is hacked, Session variables are safe.

Comment: Overall your post is way too broad to be answered in single concrete answer. Side note: "New to this" and "involved with money" is really bad combination especially since you want to implement everything yourself. It may be better idea to use off-the-shelf platforms/libraries...

Comment: alexei , i also think about that, is there any good and simple library for me to use?

Comment: Rahul, i see, i will take a look on session that part, i will see if there is any library i can use to cover my poor security skills.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove accebility of cookies by a script, preventing XSS attacks. Just use sessions, and encrypt your password with strong algorithm and a salt

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check out [DotNetNuke](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/), or DNN as it's called?  It provides all of this for you and more.  There is a bit of a learning curve, however most new things of any sophistication do.  In the long wrong, you will come out ahead time wise (and hence cost wise) and likely more secure than doing it yourself.

You can write your own modules with C#, interfacing databases as needed.  Or you can use all out of box functionality.